# Mirror the plot at certain distance from the horizontal x-axis

Tags: plotting

How to have a reflected mirrored red line at a distance of -1 in the negative y-axis.

```
gr = Plot[E^x, {x, -3, 2}];
Show[gr, gr /. 
  L_Line :> {Red, 
    GeometricTransformation[L, ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200]
```

For this I tried the sugesstion given by kglr, seem like not working.

```
ansys = {0., 0.000509954, 0.00101645, 0.00151604, 0.00200526, 
   0.00248066, 0.00293881, 0.00337627, 0.0037896, 0.0041754, 
   0.00453024, 0.00485074, 0.0051335, 0.00537516, 0.00557235, 
   0.00572173, 0.00581998, 0.00586378, 0.00584984, 0.00577486, 
   0.0056356, 0.00542879, 0.0051512, 0.00479963, 0.00437085, 
   0.00386167, 0.00326893, 0.00258945, 0.00182007, 
   0.000957637, -9.93932*10^-7, -0.00139589, -0.00294291, \
-0.00462996, -0.00644498, -0.00837593, -0.0104108, -0.0125378, \
-0.0147448, -0.0170203, -0.0193526, -0.02173, -0.0241413, -0.0265752, \
-0.0290206, -0.0314667, -0.0339028, -0.0363186, -0.0387038, \
-0.0410485, -0.0433431, -0.0455783, -0.047745, -0.0498347, \
-0.0518389, -0.0537497, -0.0555596, -0.0572613, -0.058848, \
-0.0603135, -0.0616517, -0.0628571, -0.0639248, -0.0648501, \
-0.065629, -0.0662577, -0.0667332, -0.0670527, -0.0672141, \
-0.0672157, -0.0670562, -0.066735, -0.0662518, -0.0656069, \
-0.0648011, -0.0638355, -0.062712, -0.0614326, -0.0599999, \
-0.0584172, -0.0566879, -0.0548159, -0.0528056, -0.0506618, \
-0.0483896, -0.0459946, -0.0434826, -0.0408598, -0.0381328, \
-0.0353083, -0.0323936, -0.0293959, -0.0263229, -0.0231824, \
-0.0199824, -0.0167311, -0.0134368, -0.010108, -0.00675311, \
-0.0033809, 0.};
ansys = ansys/Max[Abs[ansys]];
X = Subdivide[0, 4, 100];
data2 = Transpose[{X, -ansys}];
p1 = ListPlot[data2, Joined -> False, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 25]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black}, AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All];
d = 3;
Show[p1, p1 /. 
  L_Line :> {Red, 
    GeometricTransformation[L, 
     Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, -d}], 
      ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {None, {-d}}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also compose `TranslationTransform` and `ReflectionTransform`:

```
d = -3;
tr = Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, d}], ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]];

Show[gr, gr /. L_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[L, tr]},
   PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {None, {d}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the two argument form of `ReflectionTransform`

```
tr2 = ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}, {0, d/2}]
```

as in Ulrich's answer or `AffineTransform`:

```
tr3 = AffineTransform[{{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {0, d}}]
```

to get the same result.

**Update:** For the new example in OP, since plot markers are rendered using  `GeometricTransformation` we need to apply the transformations to the second argument of objects with head `GeometricTransformation`:

```
 Show[p1, p1 /. GeometricTransformation[i_, t_] :> 
     GeometricTransformation[i /. c_Circle :> {Red, c}, tr @ t], 
   PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {None, {d}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think It works fine with the continuous plot. I had a list of values, and I plotted with circled plot marker I am still having trouble getting the mirrored image. the moment I changed to Joined->Flase to Joined -> true, I got the reflected plot

Comment: Could you please change the plotmaker as circle once and check. because it seems like it does not work for plot other than line

Comment: sorry again I lost, why it lost the mirror reflection? I tried  tweaking the - sign in your code , seems it not working for me

Comment: it works as expected in v9. in v12 there is something wrong.

Comment: @acoustics, please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

`ReflectionTransform`needs two arguments in this case

```
Show[{gr, 
gr /. L_Line :> {Red,GeometricTransformation[L,ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}, {0,-1}]]}}, PlotRange -> All,ImageSize -> 200 , GridLines -> {None, {{-1, Green}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: But there is a new line which is coming in green colour?

Comment: That's a Gridline to visualize the refelcting plane. Remove `GridLine->...`